# How can I include a database/excel spreadsheet that I made in a proposal?

Tags: formatting, research-proposal, databases, supporting-information

I'm writing my thesis proposal, and as part of the process I've converted what used to be a Word document form to collect data into a database/spreadsheet hybrid. I have to show how I'm collecting data in the proposal, and those before me have simply copy/pasted the form from its own Word document into the proposal doc. However, now that I've converted it I'm wondering how I can show the committee exactly how I'll be collecting and storing data, and do so easily and expediently. I could always copy/paste the form as others have done and note that it's now converted, but I'd like to showcase the work I put into converting it, and why it's useful to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I were reading your proposal I would rather see a description of the conversion than look at the form itself. Explain (briefly) the shortcomings of the Word document form,  the advantages of the more formal data collection process and the tools/programs you used to implement it. Then go on to say what you plan to do with the data you will have so elegantly collected.